# Can't provide initial liquidity on PancakeSwap exchange using testnet

Tags: solidity

I have created a token on the bsc testnet, and have also created a liquidity pool. I am trying to provide initial liquidity but an error is shown whenever I try to do so.

The error message is below.

> code: -32603, message: "Internal JSON-RPC error." data: {
> code: 32000, message: "gas required exceeds allowance (29885420) or always failing transaction" }

I have already called the 'initialise' method with the two tokens shown below, and have tried providing liquidity based on those two tokens, am I missing out on some steps?

I am using the pancake-swap-interface https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-interface

For the tokens, I copied the token from https://github.com/goosedefi/goose-contracts/blob/master/contracts/EggToken.sol

My token address: `0xA6dE8E037201c6Ff9ff58e7fB72fE1Dbd15D1888`

My psuedo BUSD address (copied from real BUSD): `0xA9bcCacD1D3f2EE7CA525f59c779F8c716965978`

My LP token address: `0xb513219b46307eDDcaeFd1Aac99EB16394746B28`

Thank you all, I know this isnt the correct place to ask questions about binance smart chain, but I do not know where to ask questions regarding bsc, so I am asking it here, if you guys could point me to where I can ask questions regarding bsc, I woudl really appreciate it. Also, I'm new to blockchain development hence if there are any resources on how to properly create a yield farming token, that would be great too, thanks all!

Comment: Redeploying all these contracts on testnet seems very complicated! Have you considered using ganache to fork mainnet? Basically, you would copy bsc mainnet on a local ganache node on which you can run tests for free.

Comment: thank you for replying! :-) but how do i do that? im not sure if ganache can connect to bsc network

Comment: Voting to close this question is does not appear to be about Ethereum blockchain.

Comment: bsc is a copy of ethereum, so ganache fork will work

Comment: Were you able to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for using the answering feature as a question, but I can't comment yet.
Did you manage to add liquidity at the end? How?

Comment: Binance has support: https://www.binance.com/en/support

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me suggest a much easier alternative to achieve what you want.

- [Install ganache-cli](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli)
- Deploy a ganache node by forking bsc mainnet. In terminal: `ganache-cli -f https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/`

You are now running a local test node that has a full copy of bsc mainnet. You can connect to your local test node with Remix or Metamask, for instance.

Comment: thank you for answering! sorry im new to this but what do you mean by 'a full copy of bsc mainnet' ? does it mean that all the contracts on the mainnet would be available on my local copy? and if so, does it also mean that the bnb i use would be 'fake'? meaning i can get it from the faucet to give me more bnb? thank you!

Comment: Yes and yes. All the contracts on bsc would be there. Ganache gives you 10 unlocked accounts with 100 fake bnb right away, so you don't need a faucet. You can use those to make fake pancake swap transactions. Check ganache documentation to see how you can customize your test blockchain.

Comment: okay thank you! i'll go test it out, really appreciate it! so does that mean that any functions or contracts supported on bsc mainnet would also be available on my local host? because the issue with my testing thus far is that i've been using the bscscan testnet, and apparently i've been trying to 'add liquidity' through pancake swap, but it keeps failing, and after consulting some people in the pancakeswap telegram group, it seems like pancake swap does not support testnet functionality? altho im not sure how that works out since the contract should dictate the functionality.

Comment: Any function or contract on bsc mainnet should work on your local ganache node right away, but every transaction that you make will only be saved on your local node and not on the real mainnet.

Comment: hi so sorry to bother you, but after running a local test node with a full copy of bsc mainnet, i went to run truffle migrate in order to deploy my contracts to that local copy, but i received this error 'Returned error: Returned error: missing trie node 39b471f11145d529650de7fe45283b856787abeb34fda57de9fa3d86d526cc8e (path ).', do u have any idea whats causing this?

Comment: When I saw this in the past, I think that it was either because I was trying to access data in a past block (I think that ganache only allows you to query the latest block), or ganache made too many requests to https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/ and the API just blocked me. Sometimes I would get that error, do the same thing a bit later and not get the error. So, I'm not sure...

Comment: Any idea on how to avoid this forking BSC?

Comment: @jason I found out that if you run your tests or migrations too long after running the `ganache-cli` command then it will return that error

Answer (score 3):

Use the pancakeswap contract directly on bscscan testnet: https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1#writeContract

Comment: No need to use this contract - pancake swap testnet supports this - simply go to liquidity and paste your token's contract and create a pool and add liquidity https://pancake.kiemtienonline360.com/